Ubuntu 24.04 fails to hibernate because of Nvidia but I have AMD Radeon card..?
A bit strange problem.  Hibernation worked until I now upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS a few days ago.
As after each upgrade the hibernate options are gone and I have to activate them again.  But first I test hibernation.  And there it goes wrong.
$ sudo systemctl hibernate

Call to Hibernate failed: Invalid argument
Failed to start hibernate.target: Unit nvidia-resume.service not found.

Where the strange part is that I don't have any NVidia hardware in my computer but it is AMD processor and an AMD Radeon RX 7600 graphics.
How do I explain Ubuntu I don't have any Nvidia hardware?  Or better: how do make hibernation work again?
Funny part was indeed during a software upgrade I saw some Nvidia packages being upgraded.  Maybe I had at some point some Nvidia hardware.
Walter
ps: I will check and if needed remove Nvidia packages.  When it solves the problem I will update this topic.

I removed all NVIDIA packages and not the error is 'invalid parameter'. Note: only do this if you don't have any NVIDIA hardware. I think a solution is here. I will test it in the following days. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/2057687

Execute
cat /sys/power/resume 

If you can see 0:0 then do
lsblk  

to find the right x:x. After you found the right x:x, do
echo x:x > /sys/power/resume  

Then hibernate can work.

As written this makes no sense at all. If this is an answer it needs details.

A bit cryptic but helped me. i ran do-release-upgrade to upgrade from kubuntu 23.10 to 24.04, which failed and left my system unusable. After repairing via a usb image I then discovered that hibernation stopped working.
Because my swap was in a file I had to run findmnt -no MAJ:MIN -T /swapfile to get what @user1824568 called the "x:x" value.
When I echo'd that value into /sys/power/resume hibernate was working again.

I'm not quite sure about the Nvidia service error, but upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 broke hibernation for me. It turns out, if you are using a swap file then you need to write the MAJ:MIN values for the partition of the swap file in /sys/power/resume.
To find the MAJ:MIN of your partitions you can run:
lsblk

Then you need to write that value in /sys/power/resume(replacing MAJ:MIN with your own):
sudo echo "MAJ:MIN" > /sys/power/resume

Now sudo systemctl hibernate shouldn't give you the "Invalid argument" error. However, this value will be overwritten upon reboot to 0:0. To fix this I found a workaround in a guide by ubuntuhandbook.org, it basically adds a config file to write the MAJ:MIN values in /sys/power/resume after reboot.
sudo nano /etc/tmpfiles.d/hibernation_resume.conf

Then write the following in the file (replacing MAJ:MIN with your own):
#    Path                   Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
w    /sys/power/resume       -    -    -    -   MAJ:MIN

Now reboot then try to run:
sudo systemctl hibernate

Hope that helps!


"Hope that helps!". Yes, thanks! Also, to find which is the MAJ:MIN if  you are using a swapfile: please see the findmnt -no MAJ:MIN -T /swapfile text of another comment on this page.

